# dimnames (x) <- dn error in canonical variance analysis

Tags: r

I'm starting a CVA analysis but I get an error right at the beginning of the code, which does not happen if I use another dataset.

```
library(Morpho)
data(iris)
vari <- iris[,1:4] 
facto <- iris[,5] 
cva.1=CVA(vari, groups=facto)
```

This is the code and I'm substituting the iris data for my dataset which is very similar. However, I get this error message:

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :   length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

What does it mean?

Comment: Please specify the packages used

Comment: Are you using `Morpho` ? This looks proper and should work

Comment: Yes, I'm using the package Morpho, sorry.
It works when using the iris dataset, but when I'm using mine it does not work. 
I have a matrix of morphometric measurements of specimens of distinct species, just as iris dataset.